# Java DataReading Google Cloud Platform

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssh, datareader, calc

I have a problem, I want to upload data (openoffice calc) using java from my debian server in Google Cloud Platform and save it on my database but I can´t do this, because I need to add ssh key to my java code.

How i can connect java to Google Cloud Platform and debian instance? I don´t know how to do this.

I have:

- Java 7 on Windows 10.
- Debian server java 7
- Google Cloud Platform with assh key.

My idea:
calc → java → ssh? → google platform → instance → java → database

I use a maven repository JSch:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*Below we have declared and defined the SFTP HOST, PORT, USER 
                   and Local private key from where you will make connection */
        String SFTPHOST = "ip";
        int    SFTPPORT = 22;
        String SFTPUSER = "user";
        // this file can be id_rsa or id_dsa based on which algorithm is used to create the key
        String privateKey = "file"; 
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "folder";

        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        Session     session     = null;
        Channel     channel     = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        try {
            jSch.addIdentity(privateKey);
            System.out.println("Private Key Added.");
            session = jSch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
            System.out.println("session created.");

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            System.out.println("shell channel connected....");
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
            channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
            System.out.println("Changed the directory...");
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(channelSftp!=null){
                channelSftp.disconnect();
                channelSftp.exit();
            }
            if(channel!=null) channel.disconnect();

            if(session!=null) session.disconnect();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you scenario clearly, I think you should do it by sending data to a google cloud storage bucket: [look here](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-storage).

Also have a look about service account and credentials in gcp, it's really easy to use them on prem :)